# Define Xcode copy files build phase in CMake

Tags: cmake

My iOS project uses third-party dynamic library that needs to be code-signed and bundled into the application. In Xcode, this can be easily achieved by adding new Copy files build phases. The Xcode project is generated with CMake, however I can't find a way to define this copy files build phase. `MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION` makes the library treated as bundle resource and doesn't do code signing.

There is surprisingly very little information on the topic on the web, so does anybody know if it is possible to define Copy files build phases in CMake? Or, alternatively, is there another way to code sign and bundle third-party dynamic library using CMake?